# How can I split output from SQL Restore into Email format

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am automating process that will process refreshes for our developers using PowerShell Script and TSQL email send mail
The only thing I am stuck at putting the output of restore in email body. 
When I run Invoke-SQlcmd with restore command using *>&1, it outputs as

23 percent processed. 46 percent processed. 69 percent processed. 92 percent processed. 100 percent processed. Processed 552 pages for database 'SaveStuff', file 'SaveStuff' on file 1. Processed 2 pages for database 'SaveStuff', file 'SaveStuff_log' on file 1. RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 554 pages in 0.564 seconds (7.667 MB/sec).

The problem with this code is that it contains ' like around around 'SaveStuff' which messes up T-SQL using sql sendmail.

I got around this by using replace. It works for the time being.

The main goal is the show output individual lines instead of one long line.

23 percent processed.

46 percent processed.

69 percent processed.

92 percent processed.

100 percent processed.

Processed 552 pages for database SaveStuff, file SaveStuff on file 1.

Processed 2 pages for database SaveStuff, file SaveStuff_log on file 1.

RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 554 pages in 0.564 seconds (7.667 MB/sec).

Any suggestions

```
$RestoreResults = "23 percent processed. 46 percent processed. 69 percent processed. 92 percent processed. 100 percent processed. Processed 552 pages for database 'SaveStuff', file 'SaveStuff' on file 1. Processed 2 pages for database 'SaveStuff', file 'SaveStuff_log' on file 1. RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 554 pages in 0.564 seconds (7.667 MB/sec)."



$Restore = $RestoreResults -replace "'", " "

Write-Host $Restore



$Restore = $Restore -replace '. ', '.`n'

Write-Host $Restore
```

Comment: Why? Your developers don't care. No one really cares about those messages unless something does wrong. And when something goes wrong, your developers STILL don't care - that's your job. Your developers only care that the database was restored successfully (and perhaps when that occurred - but I doubt that as well).

Comment: `$RestoreResults -split "\.\ " -join '.'+[System.Environment]::NewLine`

Comment: @JosefZ I will give that a try too. Thanks!

Comment: @SMor The problem is that the email goes to their managers too if they request refresh. The email should look professional in case once in a while they see it :)

Comment: @JosefZ --- Thank you... that worked for what I was looking for. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "**STATS = 100**" to your RESTORE DATABASE command to eliminate these unnecessary restoring percentages.